# how to use cv::Mat imgbuf created by pointer to video data

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I am reading the raw video data from the read buffer using

```
cv::Mat imgbuf(Size(640, 480), CV_8UC3, &mem[0], (640*3));
```

This variable `imgbuf` I am passing to face detection algorithm which detects the face & draws the rectangle around the face. after that I am getting output something like

[image: output-without-resize-function]

I tried with below code where I am performing **resize operation** before pass to face detection algorithm. by using this method it is working fine. but without resizing function I am getting noticeable output with rectangle around the face.

[image: output-with-resize-function]

```
 while(1)
 {
 unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char*)mmap(NULL, page_offset + len,
 PROT_READ |PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, page_base); 
 cv::Mat imgbuf(Size(640, 480), CV_8UC3, &mem[0], (640*3));

 cv::resize(imgbuf,imgbuf,(640,480)); //Dummy function to get the right output.


 auto result = v->facedetection(imgbuf);
    for (const auto &r : result.rects) {
 cv::rectangle(imgbuf,cv::Rect{ cv::Point(r.x * imgbuf.cols, r.y * 
 imgbuf.rows),cv::Size{(int)(r.width * imgbuf.cols), (int)(r.height * 
   imgbuf.rows) } },0xff);

   }
  imshow("face-detection", imgbuf);
  waitKey(1);
```

can anybody help be to sort out this problem

Comment: Do an "imshow" right after cv::Mat imgbuf(Size(640, 480), CV_8UC3, &mem[0], (640*3)); and check if you have a valid image or not (before resizing).

Comment: @Meisam I checked before resizing function, I have the valid image. & if I remove rectangle function then also I am getting right output, It seems like rectanle function directly writing to memory.

Comment: Can anybody help me to sort out this metter

Comment: your rectangle command is a little weird for me. What information exactly is in "result.rects"? can you convert it to a cv::Rect, then try rectangling?

Comment: @Meisam yes I tried with below code for the same but results are same.             auto R= cv::Rect{ cv::Point(r.x * imgbuf.cols, r.y * imgbuf.rows),cv::Size{(int)(r.width * imgbuf.cols), (int)(r.height  * imgbuf.rows) } }; 

cv::rectangle(imgbuf, R , 0xff);

Comment: use a "cout" and print the Rect (R) values.

Comment: values like this ->   [107 x 198 from (328, 77)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this method:

```
unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char*)mmap(NULL, page_offset + len,
 PROT_READ |PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, page_base); 

cv::Mat imgbuf(480,640, CV_8UC3, &mem[0]);
cv::Mat img_2, img_3;
cv::resize(imgbuf,img_2,cv::Size(640,480));
img_2.copyTo(img_3);
auto result = v->facedetection(img_2);

for (const auto &r : result.rects)
{
   cv::Rect myR = cv::Rect(r.x * img_2.cols, r.y * img_2.rows, (int)(r.width * img_2.cols), 
   (int)(r.height * img_2.rows));

   cv::rectangle(img_3,myR,Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
}
imshow("Result", img_3);
waitKey(0);
```

After getting a valid result you can optimize this and use less of "Mat"s.

Comment: I know I will work, but  I not clear why we can't imgbuf variable, why do we need to use img_2.copyTO(img_3) function?  what are the differences between img_2 & imgbuf variable? can you help me to answer this question?

Comment: @Gagandeep It's probably the "facedetection", I don't know how exactly this function works, but it looks like somehow this function modifies and changes the input matrix.

Comment: why it is not affecting the img_2 variable?

Comment: @Gagandeep It affects that too, that's why I use img_3 for rectangling.